# ServiceStack Service Client for Universal App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, servicestack, portable-class-library

We have a WinRT app that uses the `ServiceStack.Client`. We now want to create a Windows Phone 8.1 version of it. The best option for that in terms of code reusability is to create a Universal App and share the code with a PCL.

ServiceStack has just release 4.0.30 with a PCL client library and also `ServiceStack.Text` is a PCL.

Unfortunately there is no support for the PCL Profile 111 (Windows 8 & Windows Phone 8.1). What is the best option to use a `ServiceStack.Client` with `ServiceStack.Text` in a way I can reuse my message DTO’s?

One more thing if someone from the ServiceStack read this: Since mobile connections are notoriously slow, I would prefer a more compact serialization format such as `ServiceStack.MessagePack`.

Answer (score 0):

More Information about ServiceStack's PCL support is available on the [HelloMobile Project](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile).

ServiceStack's [Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) PCL support doesn't currently support Windows Phone 8.1, it's expected to be available sometime after VisualStudio 2014 is released.

But ServiceStack's core `ServiceStack.Interfaces.dll` (i.e. the only dependency required by DTO's) is a **Profile136** PCL compatible dll that does support WindowsPhone 8. This will let you re-use your DTO's on WP clients, you just wont be able to use ServiceStack's C# Client until WindowsPhone support has been added.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Wating for VS2014 is not an option, it is too late for us. Perhaps a combination of JSON.Net and the default HTTP-Client will work for Windows Phone 8 in the meanwhile.

Comment: Just testing the things out. I can't add the ServcieStack.Interface Package to a Windows Phone 8.1 project. 
So I can't even re-use my DTO's. Windows Phone 8 is Silverlight while for Windows Phone 8.1 exists two options: Windows Phone 8.1 (targeting WinPRT) and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight (targeting the Silverlight Runtime). 
I don't want use Silverlight because I want to share parts of my Windows Store App UI via a PCL. Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

I was previously able to add ServiceStack.Interfaces to a pcl library targeting WP8 and WP8.1 but now this is not possible. Which makes things rather difficult when developing cross platform libraries targeting all platforms. Please ServiceStack, stop ignoring Windows Phone!